# @Value not getting injected in other packages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-4

I have a property source defined in Spring where I am trying to load a properties file present in the classpath

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = "classpath:prod.properties")

public class PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerConfig {

    @Bean   
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

        Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]

        { new ClassPathResource("prod.properties") };

        ppc.setLocations(resources);

        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return ppc;

    }

    @Value("${DATABASE_NAME}") private String DATABASE_NAME;

    @Bean   
    public String test() {
     System.out.println(DATABASE_NAME);

    }
}
```

> My prod.properties file has 1 entry
>
> DATABASE_NAME=proddb_123

Now in the test() bean prints as proddb_123

Two problems I am facing is

1. I have another class in a different package where I am trying to
   inject it

   @Value("${DATABASE_NAME}") private String DATABASE_NAME;

   But the value of this is always "${DATABASE_NAME}"
2. I have different gradle projects like webapplication-gradle is one
   where the @PropertySouce configuration is defined and another
   project like storage-gradle. Can I inject the DATABASE_NAME in any
   class present in storage-gradle project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other classes where you would like to inject the @Value(${DATABASE_NAME}") you have to also yse the @PropertySource annotation. Another option is to remove the @PropertySource annotations and in the applicaiton-context.xml defined a bean of class org.springframework.beans.factory.condig.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and for the property locations list add a value for the classpath:prod.properties

Comment: My Spring configuration is java annotation based config . Can you please provide me a snippet of it so that might help me to understand.

Comment: I removed the PropertySouce configurations and created beans for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer based on Profile. Later I injected all the values into a separate Bean(PropertyBean.java) and then where ever I wanted to use those properties, I just injected the PropertyBean and used from it. Thanks